# How to get the one index from array in success in ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

How to get the single index from array in ajax success function

```
$("#date").change(function(){
    var date=$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
    url:"'.base_url().'Admin/loan",
    data:{date:date},
    method:"post",
    success:function(data)
    {
      var result=data;
      $("#ddd").val(result[0]);
    }

    });
});
```

the array in like this

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "2020"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "05"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "13"
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"the single index"* ? You're already getting a single index in `result[0]`

Comment: its not working

Comment: Any error message ?

Comment: yes im trying to get single index but its not working

Comment: no. showing no thing in the alert

Comment: I doubt `"'.base_url().'Admin/loan"` is a valid URL. You should add `error` to catch the eventual errors, instead of using only success. This helps debugging

Comment: "'.base_url().'Admin/loan", its valid and working well. if i alert the array it showing result but i cant get the single index from the array

Comment: did you try logging result[0]?

Comment: i tried  alert(result[0])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given `array is not a JSON format`. Javascript won't be able to process this format. This is a `PHP Array`.

You need to convert this into JSON using [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) in your backend code and send it instead of PHP array. Then you will be able to do *result[0]* and get the relevant data.

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts/clarifications

Comment: in JSON format its output is like this 2020,05,06 then how can i get one value from it

Comment: try `alert(result[0])` after you convert to json. If that doesn't work, try `alert(typeof result)`. It will help to know if result has some different type than expected.